# What is the protocol that is being used in this Bluetooth dual SIM adapter that transfers voice and SMS?

Tags: bluetooth, adapter

I saw [this](https://www.amazon.eg/-/en/IKOS-Bluetooth-Dual-Adapter-iPhone/dp/B06WW8KBV6) product randomly on YouTube, and I'm really curious about the protocol it uses to communicate with the phone and how the phone can detect SIM cards. It uses Bluetooth for communication. For the hardware, I think it's using one of these Simcom GPRS or 4G modules. They have a built-in Bluetooth module. **I know the general idea of how it works**, what I want to know is the protocol (protocol, in computer science, a set of rules or procedures for transmitting data between electronic devices, such as computers.) that this adapter is using to transfer voice and SMS.

[image]

Comment: I would assume that the external module has a 4G radio and does all of the “ mobile phone” functions itself and then proxies the voice and data over to the phone using Bluetooth. I can’t see any way it could “present” the second SIM to the phone for it to use.

Comment: (You spelling checker dose nothing for titles.)

Comment: There is a remote sim access profile defined for Bluetooth: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#SIM_Access_Profile_(SAP,_SIM,_rSAP) . It's not that hard, conceptually, since the link between phone and it's (built-in) sim card is also just simply a serial interface exchanging commands and replies.

Comment: @MarcusMüller wonder what devices (if any) support that profile though (on the phone side).

Answer (score 2):

The product description page states that the device will only support voice and SMS, only over 2G, and has a dedicated app.

So what is more likely is that this is just a 2G modem with a BLE interface, and a dedicated app to use that modem for voice calls and SMS.

It that is the case, it doesn’t use the phone or tablet’s included modem at all, nor does it use any of its networking capabilities.

Basically it’s the opposite of a “WiFi modem” (also called a mobile router or mobile hotspot) which only delivers data, but usually not voice or SMS, over cellular, but likewise, is completely independent from the built-in modem of your phone.

In the case of the product linked to in the question, with support limited to 2G and 2G being in the process of being switched off, that’s really a niche product.

Comment: As I mentioned, I was looking for the protocol that this device is using or the phone is using to communicate with the sim adapter. I know the things that you mentioned, there are some other products like this that have 4G capabilities, and no one didn't answer my question.

Comment: @MAK it’s not actually a SIM adapter, it’s a modem which uses a SIM. The phone will not communicate with the SIM. Probably uses more or less standard AT commands over BLE too control calls and send/receive SMS. Note that the accompanying app for the product linked in your question is not available on the App Store (any more?). They have more recent devices with are just WiFi hotspots with an app using VoIP apparently. What is your goal here?

Comment: @MAK more accurately, an app on the phone could probably talk to the SIM using standard AT commands if it needed to. But it’s unlikely the phone itself (I.e. the standard phone app of the OS) will do so by itself.